# char encoding doing mysql insert with callablestatement or jdbctemplate

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, jdbctemplate, callable-statement

I am having issues with char encoding when performing an insert into a mysql table. The table field I am focused on have the following properties:

Collation:utf8_general_ci
varchar(255)

The problem occurs with chinese and foreign characters. I tried using a callablestatement to call a stored procedure but it does not work as the entry appears as follows:

```
 ?????
```

I debugged and found that the callablestatement charencoding property has this value;

```
Cp1252
```

I have not found a way to change this. I tried setting the values I insert to NVARCHAR but that too is not working. A suggestion to try the JDBCTemplate to do the insert did not work as well:

```
Object[] params = new Object[] { Num, Name, Link,type,siteid,GreetingController.StreamID };
        int[] types = new int[] { Types.NVARCHAR, Types.NVARCHAR, Types.NVARCHAR,Types.INTEGER,Types.NVARCHAR, Types.NVARCHAR };

        recordsAffected= jdbcTemplateObject.update( sql, params, types);
```

and the callablestatement code:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,info); 
        CallableStatement cstmnt = conn.prepareCall("{ call   putNewPage(?,?,?,?,?,?) }");

        cstmnt.setString(1, Num);
        cstmnt.setString(2, Name);
        cstmnt.setString(3, Link);
        cstmnt.setInt(4, type);
        cstmnt.setString(5, siteid);
        cstmnt.setString(6, GreetingController.StreamID);
```

This is frustrating. I know .NET has it as a default when working with SQL inserts to have encoding UTF-8. Any help appreciated,

Comment: what rdbms are you using ?

Comment: if the rdbms is mysql you can try running this query `SET NAMES utf8` before your statement using the same jdbc connection

Comment: Im using mysql; thanks for the response; was not sure how to do this so searched online and found quite a few negatives on doing this. http://blog.oneiroi.co.uk/mysql/mysql-forcing-utf-8-compliance-for-all-connections/

Comment: try my suggestion and let me now if it works

Comment: tried that but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include the Encoding in connection string as well  like this `jdbc:mysql://localhost/some_db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`